# Regex is not matched using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to find a regex which contains the word `Sat` followed by one or more commas. I used this:

```
sed -e 's/Sat,+/Sat/ig' myfile.txt > output.txt
```

But it has no effect despite the fact that the file contains `Sat,`. Can you correct me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` is an extended regular expression symbol, while `sed` by default uses basic regular expressions.

In a basic regular expression, you may instead use `\{1,\}` or `\+` (only GNU `sed` seems to know about `\+` and it's not standard).

You may also switch `sed` to use extended expressions by using the `-E` option.

Related:

- [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905)

Comment: I am facing another problem. If I want to match multiple regex for all week days: `sed -E 's/Sat,+/Sat/ig' -E 's/Sun,+/Sun/ig' -E 's/Mon,+/Mon/ig'` It gives an errors: `sed: can't read s/Sun,+/Sun/ig: No such file or directory`. Can you plz point why?

Comment: @qbq, ah, `-E` doesn't work as an alternative to `-e`, you just need to add it to switch to extended regexps. So `sed -E -e 's///' -e 's///'` should do what you want.

Comment: @qbq As ilkkachu said, or `sed -E 's/(Mon|Tue|Wed|...|Sun),+/\1/ig'`